# how to fix javascript exception if Oleg clickableCheckboxFormatter is used in jqGrid with single click editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Oleg message in

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/make-disabled-checkbox-of-the-checkbox-formatter-clickable/

contains clickable checkbox formatter for jqGrid.

If single click inline editing is used ( inline editing is started in beforeSelectRow event handler), clicking in checkbox column which uses this formatter causes javascript exception:

> c is undefined

in jqGrid getCellIndex method:

[image]

$(cell) value is this formatter div and c becomes undefined.

How to fix this ?

**Update**

Same exception occurs in chrome also.
Maybe div is created as direct child of body element. I patched jqGrid to return -1 in this case:

```
getCellIndex : function (cell) {
    var c = $(cell);
    if (c.is('tr')) { return -1; }
    c = (!c.is('td') && !c.is('th') ? c.closest("td,th") : c)[0];
    // AM next line added if removed single click editing in checkbox column click causes error
    if (c== undefined ) { return -1; }
    if ($.browser.msie) { return $.inArray(c, c.parentNode.cells); }
    return c.cellIndex;
},
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem which you described. I suppose it's a bug in `getCellIndex` or in the function which call it. In any way the problem is not general problem. Probably there ate some scenario when the problem exist, but you should describe exactly the test case: which version of jqGrid, jQuery, web browser you use etc.

Comment: @Oleg. Thank you. I sent testcase by e-mail to you.

Comment: @Oleg I tried to create fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net/MTRgV/19/ but this works OK. No idea what causes this

Comment: It means that the error exist not in the part wehre you suspect. Without having Test Case One can't localize the Problem. I am Not in Vocation so I can't help you much Till 4th January

Comment: @Oleg: Maybe div is direct child of body element. As quick fix I added `if (c== undefined ) { return -1; }` to getCellIndex and updated question. In this case click in checbox column using clickableCheckBox formatter does not put focus to checkbox but otherwize it works as expected. Testcase which I sent to you now contains this fix

Comment: @Oleg: in 4.4.5 this formatter does not work anymore: grid shows True and False in rows instead of checkbox. In inline editing checkbox appears always in unchecked state. How to fix this ?