# How to start inline editing on single click in checkbox column in free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm looking for a way to start inline editing in jree jqgrid if clicked in checkbox column.

Currently I'm using ClickableCheckBoxFormatter

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Checkbox.htm

desribed in

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/make-disabled-checkbox-of-the-checkbox-formatter-clickable/

and in

[how to fix javascript exception if Oleg clickableCheckboxFormatter is used in jqGrid with single click editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920810/how-to-fix-javascript-exception-if-oleg-clickablecheckboxformatter-is-used-in-jq)

I tried free jqgrid checkbox formatter.

Issues:

- If mouse cursor is placed over checkbox, mouse icon changes to disabled icon. This gives wrong hit to user like click does not work.
- Actually double click starts inline editing

How to fix those so that checkbox behaves like ClickableCheckBoxFormatter:

- Mouse cursor shape does not change
- Single click in check box starts inline edit. First click should only start inline editing. Only click in inline editing mode should change checkbox state.

Comment: I can't reproduce any from described problems. Could you provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem? Which `iconSet` you use? Which additional CSS you use? Are the problems exist in specific web browsers only? Do you start inline editing inside of `onSelectRow` (like in the referenced answers)? All my tests with `iconSet: "fontAwesome"`, `iconSet: "jQueryUI"` in IE10 and Chrome didn't show any problem. Moreover it's unclear for me why you don't use just `template: "booleanCheckboxFa"` (if you use Font Awesome of cause)?

Comment: Problem can repoduced using http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/dateInput_48_bootstrap.htm  in latest Chrome in Windows 7 Clicks **exactly** in checkbox box are ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/dateInput_48_bootstrap.htm), which you use as the reference, use **disabled** checkboxes as formatter:

```
{ name: "closed", width: 70, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "checkbox",
    edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"},
    stype: "select",
    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" } }
```

It's the origin of the problem. I would suggest you to use `booleanCheckboxFa` instead:

```
{ name: "closed", width: 70, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
```

like on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/dateInput_48_bootstrap-booleanCheckboxFa.htm) or at least the old `formatter: "clickableCheckbox"`:

```
{ name: "closed", width: 70, align: "center", formatter: "clickableCheckbox",
    edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "true:false", defaultValue: "false"} }
```

like [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/dateInput_48_bootstrap-clickableCheckbox.htm).